# Can a Quantum computer simulate classical hack and exploit in a network ? Also how would it be any different from the classical computer

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience

I'm trying to write a realistic story around Quantum computing and was wondering how different a network exploit/hack would look if a Quantum computer was to hack into a private network, instead of directly breaking the encryption.

Comment: Hi, welcome to QC! could you explain precisely what do you mean by a hack? Questions should be on-the-point, clear, if necessary provide feedback for notions that are not basic to quantum computation, and it is also good practice to clarify the motivation.